# Server won't properly send data to new clients after the first client logs in

Tags: c#, sockets, server

I'm working on a server for my 2D game programmed with the help of MonoGame and currently it has no problem logging in the first time, but when a client tries to connect after the first connection has been accepted, it stops working. I'm sorry if it's a simple mistake that I've made, but I just can't seem to find it.

I've tried putting a breakpoint at `ServerSocket.BeginAccept` and it seems like it has no problem connecting (the client's socket's Connected state changes to "true" even for the second client), I'm guessing the problem starts when it tries to send data to the second client (it very much seems like it at least), that's all I have at the moment

PS: the data that is being sent after the length packet is a login packet containing a string with a length of 2082 characters and as I first stated, the first client that connects has no problem receiving or parsing that login packet

I will keep investigating tomorrow, but until an answer has been found, any help is appreciated!

Global variables used:

```
    private static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    static BlockingCollection<byte[]> sendBuffer = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();
    public static List<SuperSocket> Clients = new List<SuperSocket>();
    public static Socket ServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

How I set up the server:

```
ServerSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 7171));
ServerSocket.Listen(50);
ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null)
```

What acceptCallback does:

```
private static void acceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  SuperSocket socket = new SuperSocket();
  socket.PlayerID = 15000; // use a generic ID before assigning the real ID
  socket.PlayerSocket = (Socket)ServerSocket.EndAccept(ar);
  Clients.Add(socket);
  socket.PlayerSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 
  SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
  ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null);
}
```

receiveCallback:

```
private static async void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        SuperSocket socket = (SuperSocket)ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            SocketError errorCode;
            int received = socket.PlayerSocket.EndReceive(ar, out errorCode);
            if(errorCode != SocketError.Success)
            {
                socket.PlayerSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
                return;
            }

            byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, dataBuffer, received);

            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuffer);
            string text_to_send;

            int playerID = map.GetPlayerByName(text).ID;
            socket.PlayerID = playerID;
            string login_data = map.GetPlayerLoginData(playerID);

            Console.WriteLine("Player " + text + " (ID: " + playerID + ") logged in");

            /* Send length */

            text_to_send = login_data;

            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text_to_send);
            byte[] length = BitConverter.GetBytes(msg.Length);

            sendBuffer.Add(length);

            /* Send message */

            sendBuffer.Add(msg);

            int count;

            while (!sendBuffer.IsCompleted)
            {
                var sendData = sendBuffer.Take();
                count = 0;
                while (count < sendData.Length)
                {
                    count = await SendAsync(socket, sendData, count, sendData.Length - count, 0);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Sent " + count.ToString() + " bytes of data");
            }

            socket.PlayerSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
        }
        catch(SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(socket.PlayerID + " disconnected");
            socket.PlayerSocket.Dispose();
            Clients.Remove(socket);
        }
    }
```

SendAsync:

```
    private static Task<int> SendAsync(SuperSocket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags flags)
    {
        var result = socket.PlayerSocket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, size, flags, _ => { }, socket);
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(result, (r) => socket.PlayerSocket.EndSend(r));
    }
```

SuperSocket:

```
class SuperSocket
{
    public int PlayerID;
    public Socket PlayerSocket;

    public SuperSocket()
    {

    }
    public SuperSocket(int _playerID)
    {
        PlayerID = _playerID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can see with your code is that `buffer` and `sendBuffer` are global variables that are shared between clients. You cannot do that.

If several clients try to send data to you, they will overwrite each other’s `buffer`. You could put the `buffer` variable into `SuperSocket`, but wherever you put it, make sure you have a separate byte array instance for each client.

As for `sendBuffer`, I don’t really get why you need that at all; can’t you just do this?

```
await SendAsync(socket, length, 0, length.Length, 0);
await SendAsync(socket, msg, 0, msg.Length, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right! The error was with the buffers, I can't believe I missed that, I've now added them to the supersocket class instead and that works very well :)

Also, the sendBuffer is just to make it easier for myself to see in what order they will be sent :)